# Outbound https proxy sidecar

Tags: proxy, kubernetes

Let's say I have a Kubernetes Job that makes https requests to changing URLs and I want to allow specific URLs only and block all other requests. My idea is deploy an *Https-Proxy-Pod* and use NetworkPolicies to make sure the *Job-Pod* can only communicate with the *Https-Proxy-Pod*. See following sketch for better understanding:
[sketch of https-proxy sidecar deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDzyV.jpg)

I know how to do that but have no idea what Https Proxy to use. As far as I understood envoy is not a suitable solution for what I want to do: https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/1606

Does anyone has a better solution or can tell me which proxy to use?

Comment: Apache webserver with mod_proxy can be used and configure http_proxy and https_proxy in environment variables with web server address.

Answer (score 1):

[Mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) is an open source tool that you can use to filter HTTP and HTTPS requests transparently using the Python scripting language.

There's also a quite detailed [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/transparent-proxy-and-filtering-on-k8s) on how to use it